# Powershell script that Pulls from at least (3) cmdlets (two can be the same) and pipes the information out a text file OR a html file

Tags: powershell

```
#Get-ChildItem get the items from the path where the script is run
# only those files are fetched which has the extension .jpg
Get-ChildItem -Path *.jpg |
#using Where-Object and using the length property of the file
#to fetch only those files which are greater 10000 in size
  Where-Object {$_.length -gt 10000} |
  #sorting the files by length using Sort-Object
  Sort-Object -Property length |
      #formatting the out to only name and length of files
      Format-Table -Property name, length | 
      #writing the file using Out-File to a text file Output.txt
      Out-File -FilePath .\Output.txt
```

i already did. But i need another script as mentioned in heading.

Comment: So what's the problem? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want collect files from several folders, and then generate your report. There are multiple ways to do it

**Example 1** (Get-ChildItem can take a list of folders)

```
$MyFolders = 'C:\Temp\','D:\Docs\','\\server01\fileShare2\'

#Get-ChildItem get the items from the several fodlers
# only those files are fetched which has the extension .jpg
Get-ChildItem -Path $MyFolders -Filter *.jpg |
#using Where-Object and using the length property of the file
#to fetch only those files which are greater 10000 in size
  Where-Object {$_.length -gt 10000} |
  #sorting the files by length using Sort-Object
  Sort-Object -Property length |
      #formatting the out to only name and length of files
      Format-Table -Property name, length | 
      #writing the file using Out-File to a text file Output.txt
      Out-File -FilePath .\Output.txt
```

**Example 2** (run several Get-ChildItem commands, combine results in an single array, and then generate report)

```
$MyFolders = 'C:\Temp\','D:\Docs\','\\server01\fileShare2\'

#Get-ChildItem get the items from the several fodlers
# only those files are fetched which has the extension .jpg
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\' -Filter *.jpg) + (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Docs\' -Filter *.jpg) |
#using Where-Object and using the length property of the file
#to fetch only those files which are greater 10000 in size
  Where-Object {$_.length -gt 10000} |
  #sorting the files by length using Sort-Object
  Sort-Object -Property length |
      #formatting the out to only name and length of files
      Format-Table -Property name, length | 
      #writing the file using Out-File to a text file Output.txt
      Out-File -FilePath .\Output.txt
```

There are more ways to archive the same results, such as using expressions $(...), arrays @(...), scriptblocks &{...}